# Use a variable to name a table I am making

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using VBA macro to make a table. First, I am inputting a date "PeriodEnd", this date filters a base table using a query. Then, I am making a second table and populating that table with (a) the results of the query, and (b) about 30 calculated fields based on the records of the query and other related tables.

My problem is that I am trying to put the PeriodEnd date in the table name and I can't seem to get the Syntax right. I am a VBA beginner, so thanks for the help. My VBA looks like as follows:

```
....
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim PeriodEnd as Date
Dim PerStr as String

Set db = CurrentDb()
PeriodEnd = #12/31/2013#
PerStr = Format(PeriodEnd, "yyyy-mm-dd")

db.Execute "CREATE TABLE TblName_" & PerStr _
& " (Field1 as LONG)
```

I've run this with syntax where the table name is static and I don't get any errors. When I run with the variable table name I get "Run-time error '3290': Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement."

Also, is there a better way to structure this? The only difference in these table will be the period end date--and the impact that a different period end date has on the underlying calculations I am forming in the VBA (functions not supported within the SQL).

Any advice on whether this should be structured instead as a query or a report (no experience yet with reports)?

Comment: Might this be better as only one table with 2 fields: period_end; and Field1?  Seems to me each of your proposed table names could be handled as a field in one master table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to create a table whose name includes dashes (because of the date format).  You will need to bracket that name.

```vb
db.Execute "CREATE TABLE [TblName_" & PerStr _
    & "] (Field1 as LONG)"
```

Also make sure to include the quotation mark at the end of the statement as I did above.

But consider using a variable to hold your `CREATE` statement.  Then you can `Debug.Print` the variable to inspect the statement you're asking the db engine to execute.

```vb
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "CREATE TABLE [TblName_" & PerStr & "] (Field1 as LONG)"
Debug.Print strDdl
db.Execute strDdl
```